# Could a Sprint Airave interfere with Wi-Fi?

Tags: wireless-networking, buffalo-router

Is it possible that the Sprint Airave is interfering with my router's Wi-Fi signal?

I have a Buffalo WZR-HP-G300NH wireless router that has been working perfectly for almost a year.

Five days ago I got the Airave in from Sprint. Hooked it up as: Modem > Airave > Buffalo

Airave works perfectly. Great cell signal through the entire house.

But now my Wi-Fi connection stops working every hour or so. The only thing that fixes it is to unplug the router and plug it back in.

Going into the router settings shows that WiFi is working perfectly. Radios are on. Some clients are even connected. But it is not true, no clients can connect in that state.

The Airave and the wireless router are sitting right next to each other physically.

Could the radios be interfering with one another? Is proximity an issue?
Is it just a coincidence that the router has gone flaky at the same time the Airave came in?

Answer (score 1):

Don't hookup your router through the Airave! That will give you double-NAT. The LAN port on the Airave (if yours has one) is for routerless setups.

Hook up the WAN port on your router to the modem. Hook up the WAN port on the Airave to one of your router's LAN ports. Do not use the Airave's LAN port.

If convenient, I'd also move them a bit further apart, just in case. At least three feet, if possible.